# Using Word Interop in C# : wrong text wrapping style after add picture into picture content control

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop, com-interop

I have a problem with picture content control's text wrapping style. Please follow steps below :

1/ I have a Word document. There's a picture content control with wrapping style is "square"
[image]

2/ In C#, I add a picture into content control above. This's my sample code :

```
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;

        object fileName = "C:\\Temp\\Pic.docx";

        var applicationWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        applicationWord.Visible = true;

        var document = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
        document = applicationWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        var contentControlsWithMatchingTag = document.SelectContentControlsByTag("Pic");

        foreach (ContentControl contentControl in contentControlsWithMatchingTag)
        {
            var cc = contentControl.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Temp\\PType.jpg");
        }



        document.Save();
        applicationWord.Documents.Close();
```

3/ In the result, wrapping style's always set to the first option "In line with text"
[image]

4/ In C# code, if I try to change wrapping style after picture's added :

```
        foreach (ContentControl contentControl in contentControlsWithMatchingTag)
        {
            var cc = contentControl.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Temp\\PType.jpg");

            applicationWord.Selection.Range.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapSquare;
        }
```

It always raises the error "The Type method or property is not available because the drawing operation cannot be applied to the current selection." (it's a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)

I'm using Win10, VS 2015 and MS Office 2016

Do you have any clue for my problem ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using Interop Services? Using the interop I have always found some issues so would recommend using something like openXML or something like this

Comment: The content control and the picture are not one entity. The content control *contains* an InlineShape object (the picture). If you format that with text wrap it removes the picture from the content control. You can insert the content control in a Textbox (the Drawing type) or a single-cell Table and format this with text wrapping, while the content control and its picture remain "in-line" with the text.

Comment: Are you OK with the information I gave you? Shall I write it up as an answer or shall we close the question as "not reproducible"?

Comment: Hi Cindy, your solution saved me.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`var cc = contentControl.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Temp\\PType.jpg");`

replace with

`var pic = document.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\\Temp\\PType.jpg");`

and change it with

`pic.WrapFormat.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapSquare;`

Comment: It would help if the answer had more details on why this works.